# Okay to set Java's network cache after program is running?

Tags: java, caching, networking

Per [Amazon's developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/java-dg-jvm-ttl.html) one should set the network cache TTL either in the file java.security via (to set to 60 seconds)

```
networkaddress.cache.ttl=60
```

or programmatically via

```
java.security.Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl" , "60");
```

My question is if it's safe to change the TTL after the code is already running. AWS's guide specifies nothing to this effect. Must this property bet set before the first DNS lookup? any time after the program is running and it will take effect? Etc.

Oracle's [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html) defines the property but does not seem to specify how to set it safely.

Only way I can think to research fully is to read the source code surrounding this value, but there really should be better documentation somewhere. Still searching.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably good. The Inet class includes the method

```
public static synchronized void setIfNotSet(int newPolicy) {
    /*
     * When setting the new value we may want to signal that the
     * cache should be flushed, though this doesn't seem strictly
     * necessary.
     */
    if (!propertySet) {
        checkValue(newPolicy, cachePolicy);
        cachePolicy = newPolicy;
    }
}
```

Which seems designed to set a new policy. The `checkValue` method makes sure you don't lax the policy as a security measure, which you're not doing in this case so it's okay.

(I'm still researching where it's used, would like something more definite.)